# SSH after typing in "ifdown --force eth0"

Tags: ssh

I have a raspberry pi on the roof of my building, and I was able to ssh into it. I was setting it up with a 3G modem, and to make the raspberry pi use the modem, I typed in `ifdown --force eth0`. I forgot to realize that will stop me being able to ssh into the pi. Is there a way I can somehow force ssh into the pi still, or is my only option going up on the roof, pulling out and inserting the power cable to reset the pi? I am still directly connected via ethernet, and the pi is still turned on.

Comment: You have slam the door leaving keys inside. have brought eth0 down, no connection in any protocol will ever reach the Pi. only solution is hard reset (power off and on).

Comment: You could try detaching the 3G modem and see if something in the networking config saves the day.  But then you have to go up on the roof anyway.

Comment: if you are sourcing power from your space inside the building setup a power strip (well labeled of course) so you can power cycle without going to the roof.

Comment: @jmsmcfrlnd Can you expand on that? Would that require a manual reset?

Comment: @freshtendrils yes, I was simply suggesting a way to power off&on your pi more easily by using the on/off button of a power strip that is more conveniently located than your roof; if you find you must reset the pi forcefully (turn power off) - you could do it without going to the roof.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions in comments are correct. Power reset is required. However, because the controller was still connected to a modem, it could connect to a server I had already set up. In the future, I could perform a reboot by loading an appropriate bash script on the controller and just telling the controller to execute the script by using a notify command in python on the server side. This uses the psycopg2 library. A reboot would prevent a power reset, and having to travel to the roof to do so.